# Scatter plot is not sort in matplotlib from csv file

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

My Code:

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.read_csv("linear_regression_dataset.csv", sep=";")

plt.scatter(df.Deneyim,df.Maas)

plt.xlabel("deneyim")

plt.ylabel("maas")

plt.show()
```

[image: result image :]

Is there a solution proposal?

**The graphic I want:**
[image: That's the graphic I want to be image:]

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow! It isn't clear what your problem is, or what you are looking for a solution to. Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) and update your question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Your values are stored as object in the `df` instead of numbers. Make sure they are numbers. Because we don't have access to the data it's not clear why you have objects, so one cannot help further.

Comment: Please clarify your question. It's absolutely not clear what your problem is, what you expect your result to be and how your current result deviates from that. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: I added the result I wanted to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sort the dataframe first and then you can plot

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.read_csv("linear_regression_dataset.csv", sep=";")
df['Mass']= df['Mass'].astype(int)
df.sort_values('Maas',inplace=True)
plt.scatter(df.Deneyim,df.Maas)

plt.xlabel("deneyim")

plt.ylabel("maas")

plt.show()
```